# report on log a call

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, tasks, dashboard, activities

I have a requirement to pull the report for the records that were created under log a call section. I knew that this log a call comes under tasks, there is no unique field that separates a normal task and log a call task. I cannot also go with subject as both the subjects are similar.

I also checked all the existing questions in stackexchange and developer forums for a solution, but didn't find any suitable one

Is there any way that i can get the report particularly for log a call records or is there any way to create custom field (like formula field/checkbox) only for log a call section so that i can differentiate a normal task and log a call task.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about this so I hit the 'Log A Call Button' in my dev org and ran a SOQL query to see if any fields had data to tell us it was a call other than the Subject line and found the TaskSubtype field had been updated by the system with the value of 'call'. I checked in reports and it is a field you can filter on.

Comment: you are a saviour!

Comment: Glad I can give back to this forum on occasion